# Asp.Net MVC slow function for retrieving random numbers from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have function called `getWords(int wrNum)` which returns wrNum number random numbers from database using entity framework and when wrNum is 300 this function takes 10 seconds of time approximately. I can't understand why it takes so much time. Please help what is wrong with my code?

```
public List<string> getWords(int wrNum)
{
    IDVLTest d3 = new DVLTest();
    for (int i = 0; i < wrNum;i++ )
    {
        string word = d3.getRandomWord().Text;
        Words.Add(new WordView { Word = word, Status = WordStatus.Right });
    }
    return Words.Select(w=>w.Word).ToList();
}

public class DVLTest:IDVLTest
{
...
    public Word getRandomWord()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int i = r.Next(DVL_Entitie.Words.Count());
        return DVL_Entitie.Words.ToList().ElementAt(i);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: have you tried not creating a new Random object each time you call getRandomWord? Just have a single Random object which is created once in the constructor of DVLTest, and within getRandomWord only call r.Next(). The documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx says "Another option is to instantiate a single Random object that you use to generate all the random numbers in your application. This yields slightly better performance, since instantiating a random number generator is fairly expensive."

Comment: And you also retrieve the entire list from the database 300 times as well. Retrieve it once and then use it repeatedly.

Comment: Yes and when I edit code how igor said It got 300 same word from database :D Thanks ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are retrieving the entire list from the database in every iteration and database access in general is expensive as it occurs out of process and usually over a network (*the database and the application/process **usually** do not reside on the same server)*. You should retrieve the list once outside of the `for` loop and then pass the retrieved list to the method `getRandomWord` as a parameter.

```
DVL_Entitie.Words.Count() // offending line
DVL_Entitie.Words.ToList() // offending line
```

Comment: Don't do a `new Random` for each call, only generate a single instance.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Igor

```
DVL_Entitie.Words.Count() // offending line
DVL_Entitie.Words.ToList() // offending line
```

DB calls are slowing this down you could try this as it would cache the number for the rest of the attempts and only requests a single item from the DB at a time not the whole DB to a list and then select the required item.

```
public class DVLTest : IDVLTest
{

    private int wordCount = -1;

    public Word getRandomWord()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int i = r.Next(this.getDBWordsCount());
        return DVL_Entitie.Skip(i).Take(1);
    }


    private int getDBWordCount()
    {
        if(this.wordCount < 0)
        {
            this.wordCount = DVL_Entitie.Words.Count();
        }
        return this.wordCount;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do as below instead pulling all data to memory:

```
return DVL_Entitie.Words.Skip(i).Take(1).FirstOrDefault;
```

If there is not too much data, Igor's solution seems the best.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.Know my code time is 0 seconds approximatly :D I like your idea @Gavin Harrison and my code is now:

```
public List<string> getWords(int wrNum)
        {
            IDVLTest d3 = new DVLTest();
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < wrNum;i++ )
            {
                string word = d3.getRandomWord(r).Text;

                Words.Add(new WordView { Word = word, Status = WordStatus.Right });
            }
            return Words.Select(w=>w.Word).ToList();
        }

 public class DVLTest:IDVLTest
    {
private int wordCount = -1;
        private List<Word> DBWords;

        public DVLTest()
        {
            DBWords = DVL_Entitie.Words.ToList();
        }

        public Word getRandomWord(Random r)
        {
            int i = r.Next(getDBWordCount());
            return DBWords.ElementAt(i);
        }

        private int getDBWordCount()
        {
            if (this.wordCount < 0)
            {
                this.wordCount = DVL_Entitie.Words.Count();
            }
            return this.wordCount;
        }
}
```